# Angular Bootstrap css : Force Last Column In a Row To Fill Remaining Empty Space

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

In my **Angular5** app, I have a container component that I'm using to declare a **row** containing some components organized in **n columns** like the following:

```
  <div class="row  mx-5 my-5 h-75 w-80">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 m-0 p-0" *ngIf="advancedSearchSrcdAccess">
      <myComponent1></app-myComponent1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 m-0 p-0" *ngIf="simpleSearchSrcdAccess">
      <myComponent2></myComponent2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 m-0 p-0" *ngIf="simpleSearchSrcdAccess">
      <myComponent3></myComponent3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 m-0 p-0" *ngIf="simpleSearchSrcdAccess">
      <myComponent4></myComponent4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 m-0 p-0" *ngIf="simpleSearchSrcdAccess">
      <myComponent5></myComponent5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 m-0 p-0" *ngIf="advancedSearchSrcdAccess">
      <myComponent6 ></myComponent6>
    </div>
     .... 
  </div>
```

As the **number of my columns (n) is variable**, and as I'm **organizing columns by 3 in every  line** (`col-md-4`)

**KO:** In some cases, the last column doesn't fill the empty space (which is my goal).

I've tried to do it with the following CSS, but it didn't solve my problem:

```
.row :last-child {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

I'm looking how to do it natively with **Bootstrap** or **Angular directives**, or some responsive CSS treatment to obtain such a final view:

[image]

Suggestions?

Comment: Instead of bootstrap classes, in this template use pure CSS flex box https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ with `justify-content: flex-end`

Comment: @Kamil That has a class built in to Bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `js` find if there are `2` or `1` column in the last row. If so, remove `col-md-4 col-lg-4` classes from the outer most column and instead use `flex-grow-1`.

## If two columns in the last row

```css
/* This code is two outline the columns */

.row>div {
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="row  mx-5 my-5 h-75 w-80">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 m-0 p-0" *ngIf="advancedSearchSrcdAccess">
    <myComponent1>
      </app-myComponent1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 m-0 p-0" *ngIf="simpleSearchSrcdAccess">
    <myComponent2></myComponent2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 m-0 p-0" *ngIf="simpleSearchSrcdAccess">
    <myComponent3></myComponent3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 m-0 p-0" *ngIf="simpleSearchSrcdAccess">
    <myComponent4></myComponent4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 m-0 p-0" *ngIf="simpleSearchSrcdAccess">
    <myComponent5></myComponent5>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 m-0 p-0" *ngIf="advancedSearchSrcdAccess">
    <myComponent6></myComponent6>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 m-0 p-0" *ngIf="advancedSearchSrcdAccess">
    <myComponent6></myComponent6>
  </div>
  <div class="m-0 p-0 flex-grow-1" *ngIf="advancedSearchSrcdAccess">
    <myComponent6></myComponent6>
  </div>
</div>
```

## If one column in the last row

```css
.row>div {
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row  mx-5 my-5 h-75 w-80">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 m-0 p-0" *ngIf="advancedSearchSrcdAccess">
    <myComponent1>
      </app-myComponent1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 m-0 p-0" *ngIf="simpleSearchSrcdAccess">
    <myComponent2></myComponent2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 m-0 p-0" *ngIf="simpleSearchSrcdAccess">
    <myComponent3></myComponent3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 m-0 p-0" *ngIf="simpleSearchSrcdAccess">
    <myComponent4></myComponent4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 m-0 p-0" *ngIf="simpleSearchSrcdAccess">
    <myComponent5></myComponent5>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 m-0 p-0" *ngIf="advancedSearchSrcdAccess">
    <myComponent6></myComponent6>
  </div>

  <div class="m-0 p-0 flex-grow-1" *ngIf="advancedSearchSrcdAccess">
    <myComponent6></myComponent6>
  </div>
</div>
```

Remember to use the latest version of Bootstrap-4 because lower version does not have `flex-grow-1`. Otherwise, use the code below.

```css
.flex-grow-1 {
  -ms-flex-positive: 1 !important;
  flex-grow: 1 !important;
}
```

---

## Update

You can use `columns.length % 3 > 0` to check if there are `two` or `one` column in the last row. If so, remove `col-md-4` and add `flex-grow-1`.

```js
var columns = document.getElementsByClassName('col-md-4');

// check if there are less than three column in the last row
if (columns.length % 3 > 0) {
  var lastColumn = columns.item([columns.length - 1])
  lastColumn.classList.remove("col-md-4")
  lastColumn.classList.add("flex-grow-1")
}
```

```css
.row > div {
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row  mx-5 my-5 h-75 w-80">
  <div class="col-md-4 m-0 p-0" *ngIf="advancedSearchSrcdAccess">
    <myComponent1>
      </app-myComponent1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 m-0 p-0" *ngIf="simpleSearchSrcdAccess">
    <myComponent2></myComponent2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 m-0 p-0" *ngIf="simpleSearchSrcdAccess">
    <myComponent3></myComponent3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 m-0 p-0" *ngIf="simpleSearchSrcdAccess">
    <myComponent4></myComponent4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4  m-0 p-0" *ngIf="simpleSearchSrcdAccess">
    <myComponent5></myComponent5>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 m-0 p-0" *ngIf="advancedSearchSrcdAccess">
    <myComponent6></myComponent6>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 m-0 p-0" *ngIf="advancedSearchSrcdAccess">
    <myComponent6></myComponent6>
  </div>
</div>
```

*I use `col-md-4` just to tell you what to do, but you must use a unique class-name so that it does not interfere with the other codes.*

```js
// unique-class-name should be used on all 'col-md-4' divs
var columns = document.getElementsByClassName('unique-class-name');
```

Comment: exactly , but how may i With js find if there are 2 or 1 column in the last row... this is my purpose

Comment: How do you render the `columns`? Do you use `loop`, `ngFor`?

Comment: no i'm putting the directly all like u saw in my example , but i have a control in each of them (*ngif) which make some of them get displayed and not the others